# Оптимизация метода рисования painter

Tags: c++, qt

Версия qt4.7.8

Есть у меня сцена размером 544x1104 на сцене рисуются прямоугольники одинаковых размеров. Внутри прямоугольника есть еще один прямоугольник меньшего размера. Вместе они образуют прямоугольник с рамкой. Цвет рамки и внутренней области разные. Каждый прямоугольник имеет свой номер. Номер никогда не изменяется. Размеры прямоугольника никогда не изменяются. Координаты никогда не изменяются. Изменяется только цвет рамки и внутренней области. Использую достаточно слабый пк и перемотка сцены очень сильно нагружают цп до 100%. Меня это не устраивает.

Написал следующий код:

```
#ifndef STATEBALANSER_H
#define STATEBALANSER_H
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include <QPainter>
#include <memorymap.h>
#include <QFont>
#include <QFontDatabase>
class StateBalanser : public QGraphicsRectItem
{
public:
    StateBalanser(int num);
public:
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);
    void StateBalance();
    void setColorState(unsigned char value_1, unsigned char value_2);
    void setColorText(QColor text);
    void setFontText(QFont fontText);
private:
    int number;
private:
    QPainterPath _painterPath;
    QRectF _intersect;
    QColor _fillColorState;
    QColor _fillColorModeWork;
    QColor _fillColorText;
    QFont  _fontText;
public:
    QRectF boundingRect() const;
    QPainterPath shape() const;
};
#endif // STATEBALANSER_H
```

.cpp

```
#include "statebalanser.h"
StateBalanser::StateBalanser(int num) :
    number(num)
{
    setColorState(DisabledBalancer,StateDisabled);
    StateBalanser::StateBalance();
    StateBalanser::setColorText(Qt::black);
    int id = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont("/usr/share/fonts/liquidcr.ttf");
    QFont font = QFont(QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies(id).first());
    font.setPointSize(12);
    StateBalanser::setFontText(font);
    _painterPath = shape();
}
void StateBalanser::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    painter->fillRect(boundingRect(), _fillColorModeWork);
    painter->fillRect(_intersect, _fillColorState);
    painter->drawPath(_painterPath);
    painter->setFont(_fontText);
    painter->setPen(_fillColorText);
    painter->drawText(boundingRect(), Qt::AlignCenter, QString().sprintf("%03d", number + 1) );
}
void StateBalanser::StateBalance()
{
  _intersect = boundingRect().intersected(QRectF(3, 3, 44, 32));
}
void StateBalanser::setColorState(unsigned char value_1, unsigned char value_2)
{ 
   switch(value_2)
   {
   case StopBalancer :        _fillColorModeWork =  QColor("#000000") ;
      break;
   case ChargeBalancer :      _fillColorModeWork =  QColor("#0000ff") ;
      break;
   case DischargeBalancer :   _fillColorModeWork =  QColor("#ff0000") ;
      break;
   case EsrBalancer :         _fillColorModeWork =  QColor("#32CD32") ;
     break;
   case DisconnectBalancer :  _fillColorModeWork =  QColor("#000000") ;
      break;
   case DisabledBalancer :    _fillColorModeWork =  QColor("#ffffff") ;
      break;
   default :                  _fillColorModeWork =  QColor("#ffffff") ;
      break;
   }
   switch(value_1)
   {
   case StateGood :      _fillColorState =  QColor("#99FF99") ;
      break;
  case  StateFiftyFifty: _fillColorState =  QColor("#FFFF66") ;
     break;
  case StateFault :      _fillColorState =  QColor("#FF9999")  ;
     break;
  case StateDisconnect:  _fillColorState =  QColor("#999999") ;
     break;
  case StateMeasurement: _fillColorState =  QColor("#a2c8d6") ;
     break;
  case StateDisabled:    _fillColorState =  QColor("#ffffff") ;
      break;
  default :              _fillColorState =  QColor("#ffffff") ;
      break;
   }
}
void StateBalanser::setColorText(QColor text)
{
    _fillColorText =  QColor(text);
}
void StateBalanser::setFontText(QFont fontText)
{
    _fontText = fontText;
}
QRectF StateBalanser::boundingRect() const
{
   return QRectF(0, 0, 49, 37);
}
QPainterPath StateBalanser::shape() const
{
    QPainterPath path;

    path.addRect(boundingRect());

    return path;
}
```

Если убрать методы

```
painter->drawPath(_painterPath);
painter->setFont(_fontText);
painter->setPen(_fillColorText);
painter->drawText(boundingRect(), Qt::AlignCenter, QString().sprintf("%03d", number + 1) );
```

То загрузка цп падает до 60%. И данные параметры никогда не изменяются. 
Но как можно убрать данные методы из paint при этом не нарушив  нумерацию, цвет, шрифт? Допустим один раз  проинициализировать в конструкторе.

Comment: нарисовать неизменную часть в QImage или QPixmap и вставить в сцену

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно завести на каждый параметр флаг-индикатор изменения. Когда вы изменяете какой-либо параметр, то флаг устанавливаете в "Изменен", а при отрисовке учитываете это. Например так:

```
void setChangeParam(<Class..> new_value) {
    this->some_value = new_value;
    this->some_value_changed = true;        
}
```

В методе отрисовки:

```
void paint(...) {
    ...
    if(some_value_changed) {
        painter->set(this->some_value);
        // Больше не отрисовывать
        some_value_changed = false;
    }
    ...
}
```

Но, у вас имеется сцена с одинаковыми элементами, у которых одинаковые параметры отрисовки, а объект painter поступает в "готовом виде" извне, тогда рекомендую наследоваться от QGraphicsView и создать методы "массового" изменения параметров.

Следите за руками:

```
class MyGraphicsView : public QGraphicsView {
public:
    MyGraphicsView(...):
        ...,
        _myScene(new MyGraphicsScene()),
        _stateBalancerFontChanged(false)
    {
        // MyGraphicsScene описан после класса MyGraphicsView
        setScene(_myScene.get());        
    }

public:
    setStateBalancerFont(const QFont& font) { 
        _stateBalancerFont = font;
        _stateBalancerFontChanged = true;
        update();
    }

private:
    QScopedPoint<MyGraphicsScene> _myScene;
    QScopedPoint<QPainter> _painter;
    bool _stateBalancerFontChanged;

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) {
        // QPainter можно создать только тогда, когда будет готово
        // устройство для отрисовки, а это метод paintEvent
        // поэтому проверяем, что паинтер еще не создан и создаем его
        if( _painter.isNull() ) {
            _painter.reset(new QPainter(viewport())); // здесь вызван именно viewport()!
        }

        // Если painter все еще null, то у нас проблемы
        if( _painter.isNull() )
            return;

        // А если нет, то все ок и мы можем рисовать:
        // подложка
        this->drawBackground(_painter.get(), viewport().rect());
        // все остальное рисуем сами
        if( _stateBalancerFontChanged ) {
            // Устанавливаем измененное значение
            _painter.get()->setFont(_stateBalancerFont);
            _stateBalancerFontChanged = false;
        }
        for(QGraphicsItem* item : _myScene.get()->stateBalancerItems()) {
            item->paint(_painter.get(), /*option*/, widget)
        }

        // Далее устанавливаем, ЕСЛИ ЕСТЬ, параметры для других
        // элементов сцены по той же схеме,
        // а потом перебираем эти элементы в цикле и отрисовываем       


        // Можно вызвать отрисовку морды, а можно не вызывать
        this->drawForeground(_painter.get(), viewport().rect());
    }
}
```

Соответственно, класс сцены должен иметь методы выдачи элементов сцены по типам 
(если таковые есть, конечно):

```
class MyGraphicsScene: ... {
public:
    QList<StateBalancer*>& stateBalancerItems() {
        return ...
    }

    QList<ItemType1*>& itemsType1() {
        return ...
    }

    ...

    QList<ItemTypeN*> itemsTypeN() {
        return ...
    }
}
```

После всех этих манипуляций, из метода отрисовки StateBalancer можно исключить следующее:

```
painter->setFont(_fontText);
painter->setPen(_fillColorText);
```

и тому подобное, а кроме того, все поля, которые мы устанавливаем "глобально". Ключевая идея, надеюсь ясна.

Кроме того, обратите внимание на метод:

```
QPainterPath StateBalanser::shape() const
{
    QPainterPath path;

    path.addRect(boundingRect());

    return path;
}
```

Он постоянно создает QPainterPath, в который добавляется один и тот же неизменяемый boundingRect(), следовательно, такие методы тоже можно оптимизировать.

Comment: Можно попросить пример ? Чтобы можно было запустить.

Comment: @zhilenkov все же детально расписано

Comment: @ Alexander Chernin Все сделал спасибо ) Я там задал вопрос про окно которое должно открываться по событию. Посмотрите пожалуйста. Не ругайте сильно.